# How are pointers compared?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
int palindrome(char * str){
char * pt1 = str;
char * pt2 = str;
    if(pt1==NULL){
        std::cout<<"\n invalid string";
        return -1;
    }
    while(*pt2 != '\0')
        pt2++;
    pt2--;
    while(pt1 < pt2){ // why does this work correctly ?
        if(*pt1 != *pt2){
            std::cout<<"\n not palindrome";
            return 0;
        }
        else{
        pt1++;
        pt2--;
        }
    }
std::cout<<"\n yes palindrome";
return 1;
}
```

hello
this is a function to check if the passed char* points to a palindrome/not.
here two pointers
pt1 - starts from begining moves fwds
pt2 - starts from end moves backwards
now i do not want them to continue once they meet in the middle..
SO i check if always pt1 
why? i am not comparing *pt1 vs *pt2.
what values does it compare ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the three concepts leading this block of code executing correctly:

1. Your pointers are operating on a continuous block of memory (the input string)
2. The pointer 'values' are addresses (basically just arbitrary numbers allocated at runtime)
3. C allocates addresses for continuous memory in a well defined, increasing manner

Due to the fact that pointers are really just integers (such as 0x000001, 0x000002 etc) you can use comparison operators on them.

Lastly due to the fact that the memory for the string will be continuous and increasing, there is a level of abstraction that you can make:  **Pointers *further along* in memory will evaluate as greater than addresses *earlier* in memory.**

Comment: s/continuous/contiguous/g :) +1

Answer (score 4):

A pointer points to a place in memory.
The value of a pointer is thus a memory address. For a given memory allocation, every byte in it is contiguous and has the next higher address assigned to it (0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002 and so on)
So, when a pointer is greater than another pointer **and both pointers belong to the same memory allocation**, it is further along in said allocation.

Comment: Nitpick: the standard doesn't require that pointers actually be memory addresses; though one could say that the requirements placed upon them imply a model of memory addresses. A conformant implementation could store segment offsets or something like that in pointers too. But +1.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers model memory addresses. Because the first pointer points somewhere in memory before the second, the less than comparison succeeds.

They don't continue when they meet in the middle because when `a == b`, then `a < b` must be false.

Answer (score 1):

There two kinds of comparison you use in your code, `pt1 < pt2` and `*pt1 != *pt2`. In the first case, you compare *memory addresses*, i.e. where in the string you are right now. Once `pt1 >= pt2`, your pointers are crossing or will have crossed. In the second case, you *dereference* pointers using the `*`-operator and compare the *values* these pointers point to.

Comment: isn't method 1 better? this is because there is a possibility that values the pointers point to could be same along the same memory line. Am i right?

Answer (score -3):

Pointers are addresses. When you compare two pointers it's comparing their addresses, which is wrong for your use. You'll need to maintain an offset or other variables of the integer kind to figure out when the positions meet.

Comment: Completely false. Comparing pointers this way has completely well defined behavior.

Comment: You'd probably be much better off literally "consuming" the string from both ends. That is actually taking a character off, alternating between the start and the end of the string. Then you don't need to compare at all, because the string will have become fully consumed (empty) when they meet and the loop terminates.

Comment: There is no technical advantage to using offset integers versus using pointers for this application. If you want to say "better" you have to show a reason why.

Comment: @chris, also "consuming" wouldn't be appropriate, there is no reasonable way to "take characters off" at each end. Moving the pointers is the most direct way of implementation.

Comment: Yes it's well defined behaviour alright, comparing addresses that's all. Which is fine when you actually want to compare two pointers are equal but not for comparing two pointers walking the same string. Even if properly de-referencing is applied it's ill advised to implement this way as not very maintainable and "shit happens" with pointers, like buffer overruns etc. When u calc and maintain offsets (integers) it's not the utterly most efficient (a few cycles perhaps) but it'll never break.

Comment: @s.bandara, I learnt C in late 80s and have since done a few more modern languages like perl. Efficiency is hardly worth worrying about these days unless you're doing heavy db operations. Saying it's inappropriate and that there's no reasonable way, especially without saying why, are not very good comments. Indeed you can consume a string, even in primitive languages like C. If you're building a compiler, instead of a little string parser, you'd opt for efficient pointer operations. Abstraction is a good thing. Use the string as an array to pop chars off each end.

Comment: I was wondering if just the addresses are compared , then can we compare any two pointers independent of their pointee type..?

Comment: @KimKardashian, yes, most likely you would do this with a "cast" between pointer types. Related to that, there is also a void pointer (void *) which could take the value of `pt1`, for example. You can't dereference it, though, as it's not pointing to anything of a type.

Comment: Two pointers pass equality if they point to exactly the same memory address, i.e. one is an original pointer and the second is a duplicate. You should not then increment and decrement these pointers and expect sane results when you compare them. Alternately if you de-reference first before the increment or decrement operations, what you do to one pointer you do to the other. Only compare two pointers because you want to know it's the same address (object) at the other end. Using a single pointer to walk a buffer is OK but this particular usecase is a bad idea imho.

Comment: go for your life and negative vote me all you like. i was already in computers when the internet was being born and I'm immune to digital bits going one way or another. Incidentally, if you learn from any lecturer or professor on the subject of programming with pointers, you'll get a similar lecture like mine. There's nothing to be gained from digging the endless pit ever more. In other words it's not constructive to approach the problem in this way, so it doesn't make sense to keep delving into manipulating two (initially equivalent pointers) and comparing them as addresses. I pointed it out.